# How to run R script by voice (or chatbot)?

Tags: r, speech-recognition, chatbot

Which R function or R package to use to run an R script via:

1. **voice** (voice command)?
2. **chatbot**?

I have developped a script that makes some tasks and I m looking for a way to run it and get output data via voice or chatbot

I have already read this one about chatbot https://www.r-bloggers.com/initiating-development-of-a-chatbot-with-plumber-and-ngrok/ but any other tutorial / ressource / R package is really appreciated.

I have also discovered this project that allows user to drive a Shiny app via voice (using Javascript) : https://github.com/yihui/shiny-apps/blob/master/voice/app.R

Comment: Thanks Henrik, I have edited my question. Does it seems ok now?

Comment: It sounds like you want to run *something* by voice, not have an R script that accepts voice input. From that, I suggest the `[r]` tag is unnecessary (as is the specificity of the script, I suggest *"is there a way to execute a program via:"*, since a script is just a program -- the interpreter -- and one or more arguments). Your question still appears to be clearly *"recommend a tool"*, so either find a specific programming question or expect it to be voted-closed as off-topic.